# How does 'Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors' work?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that in the Chrome console, when implemented below, there is a '0' field returned, and the value of length property is 1, why is that?

```
var a = {}; 
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors('a'))

// return 
{
    "0": {
        "value": "a",
        "writable": false,
        "enumerable": true,
        "configurable": false
    },
    "length": {
        "value": 1,
        "writable": false,
        "enumerable": false,
        "configurable": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`'a'` is a string.

`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors('a')` will give you the own properties of the string, which are:

- The first character of the string, at index 0, containing `"value": "a"`
- The length of the string, whose property name is `length`, containing the length of the string, which is 1

If you passed not a string but the `a` identifier, the results would be empty as you're probably expecting.

```js
var a = {}; 
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(a))
```